# Is there any way to add http endpoint as data-source in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, monitoring, metrics

I want to add a http endpoint, say http://localhost:8080 as a data-source in grafana dashboard for getting some data from the endpoint. I couldn't found nay data-source for http endpoint. Is this supported in Grafana? I am using Grafana version 9.1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana doesn't support "free-style" data sources.

It has quite a bit of datasource-specific functionality, so it is not even feasible.

All supported data source type can be found [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/).